# How to fix empty/blank notifications?

Tags: iphone, notifications

I am using an iPhone 7 on iOS 10.1.1 and I need some help!

Every time I get a notification it is empty/blank, only the name of the app is in the title. How can I fix this?[image]

Comment: With all of the apps or just one?

Comment: All off the apps

Comment: I am using iOS 10.1.1

Comment: If it's happening to every app you might have a corrupt iOS installation.  You might have to backup your data, erase the iPhone, and set it up again as a new device then add your data back.

Answer (score 1):

Same is happening to me. I'm on 10.1.1, downgraded from 10.2, but didn't notice if the issue started after upgrading to 10.2 or only after the downgrade.

I've found someone on the internet (couldn't find the link again) that suggested deleting and reinstalling each app, which I tested with one app and worked. But I'm still looking for a better solution, since it would be a real pain to delete and reinstall every single app...

For me, upgrading again to 10.2 and back to 10.1.1, but it didn't fix the problem.

Worst case, you can wipe all settings per [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/5ir4kh/bug_empty_notifications_i_downupdated_my_7_plus/) which resolved my issues on this subject.

> I went to Settings > General > Reset > Reset all settings

***Be careful not to reset settings and data*** The above option has similar wording, but only resets your settings without deleting apps content and data files / content.